# replacing an element in nested array ruby

Tags: ruby, nested

I'm having trouble locating where my issue is in my code. I want to replace specific elements with 'X' if they show up on a bingo board:

```
class BingoBoard

  def initialize(board)
    @bingo_board = board
  end

  def number_letter

    @letter = ['B','I','N','G','O'].sample
    @number = rand(1..100)

  end

  def checker
    @number
    @bingo_board.map! do |n|

      if n.include?(@number)

        n.map! { |x| x == @number ? 'X' : x}

      else

        n

      end
    end

  end

end
```

this is the test i'm using to see if my code is running, but X never shows up and I been looking over my code many times now and can't figure out why...:

```
board = [[47, 44, 71, 8, 88],
        [22, 69, 75, 65, 73],
        [83, 85, 97, 89, 57],
        [25, 31, 96, 68, 51],
        [75, 70, 54, 80, 83]]

new_game = BingoBoard.new(board)

new_game.checker
```

If anyone can provide insight on what I am missing or not seeing, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You never call your `number_letter` method. In your `checker` method @number is nil the entire time.

Comment: @menelik tucker thank you ! that's what I was missing

Comment: It's always the small things. :)

Comment: Also as a note this does not appear to actually be a bingo board as column 1 would be constrained to values `1..15` so a better initialization for the board would be something like. `Array.new(5){ |column| column_array = ((column * 15 + 1)..(column + 1) * 15).to_a.shuffle; Array.new(5) { column_array.pop } }.transpose`. This will produce a non-duplicating accurate bingo_board. Also your range for a random number should be `rand(1..75)` as 75 is the max number of a standard bingo board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BingoBoard

  def initialize(board)
    @bingo_board = board
  end

  def number_letter

    @letter = ['B','I','N','G','O'].sample
    @number = rand(1..100)

  end

  def checker
    number_letter
    @bingo_board.each do |n|
      index = n.index(@number)
      n[index] = 'X' unless index.nil?
    end

  end

end
```