# make bingo board arrays appear in neat rows as output ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

Hello I have my following bingo code that marks X for numbers that get returned:

```
class BingoBoard

  def initialize(board)
    @bingo_board = board
  end

  def number_letter

    @letter = ['B','I','N','G','O'].sample
    @number = rand(1..100)

  end

  def checker
    number_letter
    @bingo_board.map! do |n|

      if n.include?(@number)    #cleaned up code from the initial solution.

        n.map! { |x| x == @number ? 'X' : x}

      else

        n

      end
    end

  end

end
```

My question is how do I change my code so that when I'm using the test code:

```
board = [[47, 44, 71, 8, 88],
        [22, 69, 75, 65, 73],
        [83, 85, 97, 89, 57],
        [25, 31, 96, 68, 51],
        [75, 70, 54, 80, 83]]

new_game = BingoBoard.new(board)

new_game.checker
```

It will appear neatly like a bingo board in irb.

Right now it looks like:

```
=>[[47, 44, 71, 8, 88], [22, 69, 75, 65, 73], ["X", 85, 97, 89, 57], [25,     31, 96, 68, 51], [75, 70, 54, 80, "X"]]
```

Comment: You had a similar question before and my answer gave you the response you are looking for now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612258/replacing-an-element-in-nested-array-ruby/29612723#29612723

Comment: check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496273/placing-sub-arrays-in-neat-rows

Answer (score 1):

Append `.map { |block| puts block.inspect }` to the `new_game.checker` call.